# Update error (Stretch) - Raspberry Pi 3 b+

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm new in raspbery and I bought the raspberry pi 3 b+ version.

when I try to `sudo apt-get update` it always error.
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org' and Err:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like network problem.
Do you have configured network properly?
Can you `ping google.com` for example?

Comment: I just change the nameserver into 8.8.8.8 and nameserver 1.1.1.1

Comment: how to save it permanently? because when I reboot it always go back to the previous

Comment: edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add the following line to the end: `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`. If it changes after reboot, you need to edit `/etc/dhcpd.conf` there should be line `static domain_name_servers=` there you can put list of nameservers separated with space. Let me know, which solution works for you.

Comment: I put the nameserver 8.8.8.8 and nameserver 8.8.4.4 to resolv.conf... and in interfaces I didn't put anything..

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too. I did these steps and it fixed but i dont know why

Firstly tried ping to google.com and it was succesful.

```
ping -c3 google.com
```

I searched internet and i thought change /etc/apt/source.list

```
sudo nano etc/apt/source.list
```

I commented out below link in source.list and i tried again and failed again. After that i undo changes.

> #deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

And i tried

```
sudo apt-get update
```

again. And it worked. I dont know why this worked but it worked for me.